# How to create a list of lists for family tree

Tags: python, list

New to python. Learning to create a function that results a list of lists... for example, something that can represent a family tree.  Here is what I came up with:

```
def familytree(root):
        many = int(input('How many children does "' + root[0] + '" have? '))
        if many > 0:
            root.append([[] for y in range(many)])
            z = root[1]
            for j in range(many):
                name = [input("Give name of one of " + root[0] + "'s children?")]
                z[j] = name
                familytree(name)
        print(root)
```

Seems to work...

```
['A', [['B', [['D', [['G'], ['H']]], ['E', [['I']]]]], ['C', [['F', [['J'], ['K']]]]]]]
```

... but results unnecessary brackets and print outputs.

Any suggestions for better implementation?

Will work on a Class structure next.

Comment: Please refactor using code indentations.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change the way the list is printed?

Comment: Not really. In addition the the final result I entered above, the function prints many intermediate steps. For example:
['f', [['j'], ['k']]]
['c', [['f', [['j'], ['k']]]]]

Comment: What would the intended output look like? `A` has 4 children, I give it name `B` as a single example... then what? How many generations go in, and how do you fill a generation? How do you represent offspring of `B` in a list that classifies him as part of the same generation as `C, D, E` who have their own, distinct, descendants?

Comment: The function asks you to name each child individually, in a depth first fashion.  You can fill in as many generations as you desire.  For example, if root ["A"] has 2 children (named B & C), then B has 1 child (named D) and C has 2 (named E & F)... when prompted for names, you would sequentially add them in this order:  root A --> B --> D --> C --> E --> F. (Note: this example is different from my original post)

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can only print the final result. I've also simplified some other stuff to make it a little clearer.

```
def familytree(root):
    many = int(input('How many children does "' + root[0] + '" have? '))
    if many > 0:
        z = []
        root.append(z)
        for j in range(many):
            name = [input("Give name of one of " + root[0] + "'s children?")]
            z.append(name)
            familytree(name)


root = ['A']
familytree(root)
print(root)
```

Answer (score 0):

One simpler approach without breaking your code:

```
root = ['A']
def familytree(root):
    many = int(input('How many children does "' + root[0] + '" have? '))
    if many > 0:
        root.extend([] for y in range(many))
        for j in root[1:]: 
            name = input("Give name of one of " + root[0] + "'s children? ")
            j.append(name)
            familytree(j)

print(familytree(root))
```

You might also make use of [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) built-in library to pretty-print objects